# Do transfer from friends show as income?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, banking, transfer

I'm going on trip to Australia in a few weeks and as I work in the city of London, I get a great exchange rate.

I told my friends I can exchange their currency too. ( They live outside London)

Just wondering if the transfer in of funds from friends will make my bank think I'm earning more or is there some type of limit? It might be a daft question.

Comment: Just a random angular comment, James. I would never do this to save a few pennies (or to help your friends save a few pennies). Unless your mates are changing literally 7 figures the saving is nothing.  "wondering if the transfer in of funds from friends will make my bank think..." ANY suspicious activity gets KYC'd, as you probably know working in the city. Sure, if it's less than 10k you're less likely to have a problem, but we live in Orwellian times as far as money movements are concerned - why invite problems?

Answer (score 3):

Your bank won't care about the money coming in unless it's enough to make them think you're money laundering (tens of thousands of pounds), and even then it's only likely to trigger a review rather than actually creating a problem.

Bank accounts sometimes have limits on transfers out/withdrawals per day, but again those are typically in the thousands (or hundreds for cash).

There also won't be any tax consequences as you're not doing this as a business or to make a profit. In theory if HMRC audited you they might ask about it, but it would then be easy for you to explain, and it's very unlikely they actually would anyway.